# VSC gives expression must have a constant value error despite using const

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am getting an error like this despite using const. `Var` in this case comes from an enum. Compiling works without errors or warnings. I assume this is issue with vsc or something

[image: vsc error]

This code will compile and run without errors

```c
#include <stdio.h>
typedef union {
    const char *s;
    int i;
}Variable;

enum {
    a = 0, 
    b,
    Var,
};

const Variable var2 = {.i=Var};
Variable p3[][3] = {
    {var2, "test", {.i=5}},
    {{.i=Var}, "test2", {.i=50}}
};

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", p3[0][0].i);
    printf("%d\n", p3[1][0].i);
}
```

Comment: Please post the error as a text block, don't post the image of the text.

Answer (score 4):

An initializer for an object with *static storage duration*, which includes file scope objects, must be a *constant expression*.

The C standard does not explicitly allow for `const` qualified file scope objects to be considered a constant expression.  VSCode is printing an error message in the IDE because of this.

However, implementations are allowed to accept other types of constant expressions.  In gcc starting with version 8, a `const` qualified file scope object is in fact considered a constant expression, and thus your code compiles on that version of gcc and later.  gcc versions 7.5 and earlier will report an error when trying to compile this code.

Comment: The error I am getting comes from this extension with Error Squiggles enabled
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools

I tried setting different Intelli sense modes but the error persists

Comment: "However, implementations are allowed to accept other types of constant expressions" Yeah but then they can no longer guarantee that strictly conforming programs get the correct diagnostics, because a program with an object taking a `const` qualified object as initializer is not strictly conforming. gcc is all over the place here, they changed the behavior even though the C standard never changed in this aspect (at least not until C23 with constexpr). Quality implementations would at least produce a diagnostic with `-pedantic`. gcc and clang do not.

Answer (score 2):

`const` variable **is not** a constant expression.

What is constant expression:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall
> only have operands that are integer constants, enumeration constants,
> character constants, sizeof expressions whose results are integer
> constants, and floating constants that are the immediate operands of
> casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
> convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an
> operand to the sizeof operator.

Comment: But compiling and running the code doesn't produce errors and doesn't seem to cause any issues so should I even take that error from vsc seriously ?

Comment: @nescius most likely you compile it as `C++` which is a completely different language than `C`

Comment: I didn't comile it as C++. You can try the code I added to the question. It works in this online C comiler for examle. Just vsc is giving an error for whatever reason. https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/online-compiler/

Comment: @nescius MSVC accepts the enum `Var` to initialise with, but `var2` is a `union`, not a constant expression. I don't get how you can get a compilation error, but run the program.

Comment: @Weather Vane Not sure what are you trying to say. As I said the code works when compiled and run. {.i=Var} right below var2 is also an union and there are no complaints from vsc. Also I compile with gcc. Currently I think it's vsc that's just giving me false error considering the code runs so I want to know where I am wrong if I am

Comment: Soory, if you get a compilation error, there won't be an executable to run. Please be clear.

Comment: It seems that starting with gcc 8 it allows using `const` qualified static objects as initializers for other static objects.  Even `-pedantic` give no message for this usage.

Comment: @Weather Vane To clarify more the error comes from C/C++ extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools when "Error Squiggles" is enabled in settings. But the compilation itself didn't cause errors so I could run it

Comment: You are quoting the definition for "_integer constant expression_", but that is not actually required in an initializer. See the following paragraphs in the standard.